# Possible to attach INPUT element to multiple forms?

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to attach an input element to more than one form? I know HTML5 allows you to specify a form an element belongs to by form's ID. But is it possible to attach it to like multiple ID's?

It seems nice to do all that without any javascript/JQuery, which is the alternative.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have several forms that do a search, in different ways, and wanted to add a common field to all those forms. The thing is I dont want to redo the whole page to make them all to one form (which I should have done in the first place, but don't want to do that now)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, a form control can be associated with only one form.

From [w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/semantics.html#attr-fae-form):

> If a [reassociateable](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/semantics.html#category-form-attr) [form-associated](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/semantics.html#form-associated-element) element has a [form attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/semantics.html#attr-fae-form) specified, then that attribute's value must be the [ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/semantics.html#concept-id) of **a** form element in the element's owner [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/semantics.html#document).

You can use a single, large form and decide (on the server) which inputs to pay attention to based on which submit button was pressed.